# Obtain element width & height when I didn't set it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML element but I have not defined the width or height (or sometimes I may not have defined the right or bottom, but I did define the width & height) in CSS.

Do you know how I can use JavaScript to obtain either an elements width or height or right or bottom if I haven't set it?

```
#blockMenu { z-index: 0; padding: 10%; }
```

If I do the following, I know it wont work because I didn't set the width or right:

```
var width = document.getElementById("blockMenu").offsetRight - document.getElementById("blockMenu").offsetLeft;
```

**Is there anyway to determine the dimensions & position of a element when I haven't set it?**

If not what if I define the width; how do I obtain the elements width through JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScript you can do

```
document.getElementById("blockMenu").clientWidth;
document.getElementById("blockMenu").clientHeight;
```

With jQuery you can do

```
$('#blockMenu').width();
$('#blockMenu').height();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7jteV/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you have the option to use jquery, you can use the [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery as well

> $("blockMenu").width() 
>   $("blockMenu").height()

http://api.jquery.com/width/ 
http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("blockMenu").style.width
document.getElementById("blockMenu").style.height
```

Should do the trick

Comment: This will not work if the element does not have an inline style for width and height defined.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking for a way around this method, as this won't work if the sizes haven't previously been explicitly set.