# Determining the Width and Height of an element: True and normal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know what the best method is to calculate the width and height of an element with Jquery/Javascript (or any other method that might be more accurate). Currently, I am using this Jquery method:

Jquery: See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/AwkF5/1/

```
var w = $("#wrapper"); //The element dimensions to calculate
$("#displayW").text( "outerWidth:" + w.outerWidth()+ " , outerWidth(true):" + w.outerWidth(true) ); // Displaying the width in the #displayW div
$("#displayH").text( "outerHeight:" + w.outerHeight()+ " , outerHeight(true):" + w.outerHeight(true) ); // Displaying the height in the #displayH div
```

Now is this the most accurate way to calculate the width/height(including content, padding and border) and TRUE width/height ((including content, padding, border and margin) of an element?

What would be the plain javascript method?

I'm asking because I want to make a background image for the div and I want to know what size it should be...Note that the width and height varies between different browsers...obviously

Thank You

​

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain element width & height when I didn't set it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385624/obtain-element-width-height-when-i-didnt-set-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var realWidth = $("#yourBlockId").outerWidth();
realWidth += parseInt($("#yourBlockId").css("margin-left"), 10);
realWidth += parseInt($("#yourBlockId").css("margin-right"), 10);
```

The same approach for height.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how does this method differ from mine? Is it better/more accurate?

Comment: Basically, it is better to write a functions getRealWidth() and getRealHeight() and use them instead of repeating the same block of code every time. But that is pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate. What is the 10 for at the end of the realWidth statement? Also, do you repeat that code for the height like I did?

Comment: @DextrousDave That number represents the numeral system to be used. You can take a look on parseInt() function here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: How would you display the values?

Comment: `alert(yourVariable)` to create a notification window, `document.write(yourVariable)` to print inside the document. Take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp